# Jhipster import-jdl not generating entities

Tags: microservices, jhipster, jdl

I am running into a problem with import-jdl and I am not sure why it is not working. I am trying to generate entities for microservices application.

All I get is

> The jdl is being imported.

but nothing else.

I used the sample https://jhipster.github.io/jdl-studio/ entity provided by JDL without any modification.

I have tried this in my Mac, Linux (Ubuntu), and Docker container but I get the same error.

Here are the versions of the software:

```
JHipster Generator: v3.3.0
npm : 3.9.2
yo : 1.8.3
```

> Microservices Application
>
> ------- Application files will be generated in folder: /Users/anand/Desktop/jhexample
>
> ---
>
> JHipster update available: 3.4.0 (current: 3.3.0)   Run npm install
>   -g generator-jhipster to update.  ______________________________________________________________________________
>
> ? (1/16) Which *type* of application would you like to create?
>   Microservice application
>
> ? (2/16) What is the base name of your application? jhexample
>
> ? (3/16) As you are running in a microservice architecture, on which
>   port would like your server to run? It should be unique to avoid port
>   conflicts. 8081
>
> ? (4/16) What is your default Java package name? com.anand
>
> ? (5/16) Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT
>   authentication (stateless, with a token)
>
> ? (6/16) Which *type* of database would you like to use? MongoDB
>
> ? (7/16) Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the
>   backend? Maven
>
> ? (8/16) Would you like to enable internationalization support? No
>
> ? (9/16) Which testing frameworks would you like to use? (Press
>    to select)Gatling

...snip...

> Server app generated successfully.

```
anand$ yo jhipster:import-jdl ./jhipster-jdl.jh
```

> The jdl is being imported.

Comment: read jdl studio documentation, you defenetly get an answer for this https://jhipster.github.io/jdl/

Answer (score 7):

I've faced the same situation: The jdl is being imported but nothing is generated. As Vikas Joshi suggests try using jhipster-uml:

```
npm install -g jhipster-uml
jhipster-uml ./jhipster-jdl.jh -db mongodb
```

jhispter-uml usually returns more feedback. Anyway take into account that in MongoDB as noSQL database that it is, some options have no sense (e.g relations between entities).

Answer (score 3):

if you are here because your jhipster import-jdl youfile.jdl doesn't create java code for entities but reportes the entities are imported, please try

jhipster import-jdl youfile.jdl --force

Comment: Thanks mate, I had this problem after switching from windows to ubuntu, idk if there's a relation, anyway adding --force made import-jdl generate the missing files.

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with the same error (for MySql i.s.o MongoDB). I used jhipster-uml i.s.o jhipster:import-jdl to create Entities and it worked for me. Hope it works with MongoDB as well. Don't exactly know why it does not work with import-jdl.

Answer (score 1):

I've run on the same issue on my OSX. Currently I've managed to workaround this through a virtual-machine on linux(debian/ubuntu) using the jhipster-generator version 3.4.0 . Newer version will not create the entities even for me.

Please try to delete all stuff installed from bottom to top from the instalation guide [here](https://jhipster.github.io/installation/) until nodejs part.

So yo will done the following:

```
npm uninstall -g generator-jhipster
npm uninstall -g gulp
npm uninstall -g bower
npm uninstall -g yo
```

Then follow steps to remove nodejs from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/1009448)

After uninstalling start again installing nodejs and commponents as suggested on jhipster guide with the only difference at the last step:

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster@3.4.0
```